# heavily timbered park vs. a grove, which is thicker?

Tags: synonyms

Quote:

A heavily timbered park stretched up in a gentle slope, thickening into a grove at the highest point.

The text comes from The Adventure of the Speckled Band, a short story that was written in 1892.

i thought park in British English meant "woodland" or "forest", while "grove" meant "a small wooded area or plantation".

Then how come "a heavily timbered park" can be thickening into a grove?

Comment: I think the distinction is in how dense the trees are. I've seen a hiking guide book describe a sparse area of (naturally-growing) forest as having a "park-like atmosphere"; that is, the trees were spaced fairly distantly, without open ground between. A grove is [partly defined by](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/grove) the dense arrangement of the trees. I would take "heavily-timbered park" to mean "having a lot of trees, but still not densely packed."

Comment: In addition to @AndyBonner's comment, it's possible the trees  thinned out ("stretched up") at the edge of the park, but then thicken again in an identifiable grove.

Comment: The usage is dated and confusing nowadays. Parkland, the idealised landscape championed by say Capability Brown, is (usually rolling) fields dotted with occasional large trees and/or small clumps of trees. A heavily-timbered park sounds contradictory to me, but one can perhaps picture half grass, half stands of trees, with reasonable spacing of these (grassed and treed) areas. The 'grove'  mentioned seems little different to a largish clump; I'd have had 'small wood'.

Comment: In British English, a "park" can be anything from a children's play area much smaller than a football pitch to something like Snowdonia National Park, which is thousands of square kilometres. I'm voting to close on the grounds that it's all a matter of opinion, and opinions vary.

Comment: _Park_ has a number of meanings, but none of them equates to _forest_ (though a National Park could be a largely wooded area).

Comment: @KateBunting: how confusing then that two of the UK's national parks - Queen Elizabeth Forest Park and Argyll Forest Park - are both parks and forests, or at least are named to suggest that they are!

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - But if _park_ meant _forest_ by definition, there would be no need to specify that they were 'forest parks'! Other National Parks include Dartmoor and the Norfolk Broads.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth A heavily timbered parkland also sounds contradictory in the intermountain west of North America, where it is a term of art for a particular topographical feature: "a wide, flat-bottomed valley in a mountainous region".  OED says it's esp. used in Colorado and Wyoming. Think of the adult comedy cartoon series _South Park_ set two miles high in Park County, Colorado (in Fairplay, actually, where you can visit the old pioneer town of South Park). All these uses of *park* are for the flat and mainly treeless high valley there. Nobody much knows this these days. It's a special use.

Comment: @tchrist I'll have to stick to Currier and Ives. Bringing the magnificent western vistas to the deprived city-dwellers ... and then the city-dwellers to deprive the west. I should talk; Catherine and I have indulged in 3 coach (sorry, bus) trips to the SW and West.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You probably really did travel on a coach not a bus, even here. Local usage holds that a *coach* is a bus with pretensions of luxury that’s used for long distance or charter trips. A bus is like for school kids or local public transport within a big, dirty city. The snooty petite bourgeoisie would never be caught dead on a *bus* because that's what people too poor to own their own vehicle use to get to work and back again, but they'll gladly get on a tour company's *coaches*. I think the only difference is that there's a loo at the back of a coach. :)

Comment: @tchrist Yes, they all had loos we weren't supposed to use (far from being the case with typical British coaches, at least up until fairly recently, though they _are_ always up-market when compared to single-decker buses. We have the occasional twin-decker coaches too now.) But one was inscribed with a huge 'Le Bus'.